# How to embed iTunes metadata into the actual files?

Tags: itunes, video, metadata, mp4

I really struggle working with iTunes on Windows XP Pro sp3.

I have lots of mp3s, movies and TV shows, but it is a huge pain to get all the metadata into iTunes in the first place.

Then I tried looking at the files in Windows Explorer, and the data is just not there, not in the extra columns, not in the properties.

How can I get all the data put into the actual file properties?

Comment: What version of iTunes are you using?

Comment: The latest version, 10.5.3.3. I always check for updates.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is with Windows XP and not with iTunes.

iTunes does indeed put the meta-data into each music file, according to the standard ID3 meta-tag specification.

I have checked with my iTunes 10 library in Windows 7, and Windows Explorer in Windows 7 displays the meta-data for those music files from iTunes correctly.

I can't test this, not having a Windows XP system anymore, but I wonder if perhaps Windows Explorer in Windows XP displays file meta-data in some different manner that causes it not to recognize the ID3 tags placed in the files by iTunes 10.

I know that the way that Windows Explorer displays meta-data changed radically when Windows Vista was released, and works basically the same way in Windows 7.

I suspect that iTunes works fine with Windows Vista and Windows 7 in this respect but that Windows XP, being a 2001 technology and more than a decade out of date, doesn't do this according to the standard "modern" Windows conventions.

Here is a file from iTunes 10 displayed in Windows Explorer in Windows 7.

[image]

Comment: Can you show me a screenshot of how it show's the metadata in Windows Explorer? I am more interested in movie/tv show metadata being visible.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that iTunes will force write to the MP3 if you input all the meta data in and paste the artwork, press OK, and then go back to the Artwork Menu, select the artwork, use CTRL + X (Cut) and CTRL + P (Paste) and click OK to force it. After that, then all the metadata starts showing in Windows Explorer along with all my other devices.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [MP3Tag The Universal Tag Editor](http://www.mp3tag.de/en/) I found it on Google and it looks like it will allow you to edit the metadata tags for MP3 as well as a bunch of other files.

**EDIT:**

Here is a [link](http://digitalconfidence.com/MetadataTouch.html) to a MetaData editor that can edit Microsoft Office® documents (Word, Excel®, and PowerPoint®), OpenOffice.org documents, JPEG, JPEG 2000, AVI, MP4, F4V, WAVE, PNG, SVG, and XMP files. So it should work for you. However it costs money. The cheapest version is about 60 dollars...

Comment: Isn't that just for the mp3's? What about the movie and tv shows which are the real problem?

Comment: I will be honest, This is the type of thing I love iTunes for. I can edit a bunch of different media files at once if and much faster than using the file system.

Comment: I always recommend kid3 as tag editor.